# C++ Read Access Violation,0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c++, pointers

I have written a linked list based queue, where each node is linked to the node behind it in the queue. Every other function in the program works with no problems. For some reason this destructor is giving me some issues, and I am not sure why.

I am getting this error:

> **Exception thrown: read access violation.
>   temp was 0xCDCDCDCD.**

Thanks for any help given.

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"

template <typename T>
class LQueue
{

    Node<T>* front;
    Node<T>* end;

    int length;

public:

    LQueue();
    ~LQueue();

    //Add item into queue
    void enqueue(T x);

    //Remove item from front of queue
    void dequeue();

    //return item at front of queue
    T peek();

    //Is queue empty?
    bool isEmpty();


    int getLength() { return length; }
};

template<typename T>
inline LQueue<T>::LQueue()
{
    front = nullptr;
    end = nullptr;

    length = 0;
}



template<typename T>
inline void LQueue<T>::enqueue(T x)
{
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
    temp->data = x;

    length++;

    if (isEmpty())
    {
        temp->next = nullptr;

        front = temp;
        end = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        end->next = temp;
        end = temp;
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline void LQueue<T>::dequeue()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        std::cout << "\n[!] Empty Queue, Nothing To Remove.\n";
        return;
    }

    if (end == front)
    {
        delete front;
        front = nullptr;
        end = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T>* temp = front->next;
        delete front;
        front = temp;
    }
    length--;
}

template<typename T>
inline T LQueue<T>::peek()
{
    return front->data;
}

template<typename T>
inline bool LQueue<T>::isEmpty()
{
    if (front == nullptr)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
template<typename T>
inline LQueue<T>::~LQueue()
{
    Node<T>* temp = front;

    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        Node<T>* temp2 = temp;
        temp = temp->next;

        delete temp2;
    }

}
```

[Error from visual studios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBumZ.png)

Comment: Please post your entire C++ source code and the full error message.

Comment: It seems that `front` was not initialized. Some compiler use `0xCDCDCDCD` as initial value for uninitialized variables in debug builds.

Comment: `0xCDCDCDCD` is a common Visual Studio debugger value for uninitialized heap memory. It seems you're forgetting to initialize some member variables in a constructor somewhere.

Comment: I added whole class @pts , and also I believe I do believe I initialized front

Comment: Please also add the main function, so we can see how you use this class. The main function should be short: construction, and call a few methods to trigger the bug.

Comment: `front` is initialized, but `end->next` is not initialized for every list longer than 1 (unless `Node<T>` takes care of that by itself).

Comment: A [mcve] should be able to reproduce the problem.  The code provided is incomplete.

Comment: Aside: `peek` does not check for empty.

Comment: Thanks @Yksisarvinen, I have fixed the problem because of you.

Comment: Simple solution: Add a `Node<T>` constructor which initializes the `next` member properly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Yksisarvinen, I have fixed my problem.

The end->next was only initialized if the queue was empty. I didn't initialize end->next if queue wasn't empty.

Old Code

```
template<typename T>
inline void LQueue<T>::enqueue(T x)
{
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
    temp->data = x;

    length++;

    if (isEmpty())
    {
        temp->next = nullptr;

        front = temp;
        end = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        end->next = temp;
        end = temp;
    }
}
```

New Code:

```
template<typename T>
inline void LQueue<T>::enqueue(T x)
{
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
    temp->data = x;

    length++;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    if (isEmpty())
    {


        front = temp;
        end = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        end->next = temp;
        end = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: As the comment in the main section stated, you should initialize `Node`'s members in the `Node` constructor.  You shouldn't create objects with members that have an uninitialized state.